# Fuerza bruta selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hola me olvide la contraseña de mi usuario y no la anoté en ningún lado.

Escribí este código pero no se como seguir para que haga refresh hasta que la contraseña sea la correcta. El input de la contraseña tiene un maximo de 32 caracteres. Lo que me acuerdo es el usuario.

Hasta ahora voy bien? Como podría seguir?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from playsound import playsound
import smtplib, ssl
from random import sample


def password_generator(longitud):
    abc_minusculas = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    abc_mayusculas = abc_minusculas.upper()

    numeros = "0123456789"

    secuencia = abc_minusculas + abc_mayusculas + numeros

    password_union = sample(secuencia, longitud)

    password_result = "".join(password_union)

    return password_result


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("http://siga.frba.utn.edu.ar/")
print(driver.title)

link = driver.find_element_by_id("page-try")
link.click()

time.sleep(1)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-page-try"]/p[4]/a')
link.click()

time.sleep(1)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("form_email")
search.send_keys("35335")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Tienes acceso al email con el que te registraste? No sería más facil contactarse con la universidad y pedir que te restablezcan la contraseña?

Comment: @braver Ya lo he hecho y esta caida la pagina para restablecer la contraseña

Comment: pero hombre esto es como ver una hormiga y sacar un lanzallamas XD... A lo mejor puedes llamar por teléfono o algo un poco más simple, ya que un ataque bruteforce... En el mejor caso te bloquean la IP, en el peor caso se puede considerar hasta ilegal..